# Getting error nonetype object is not callable, how do i remove this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`This is the program to print a list of remainder by dividing a list by a given number, also I don't fully understand how to create a decorator would be helpful if someone could explain.

```
# to print array of items of remainders
number_in_array = int(input("How many numbers do you want in the array? "))
array = []
remainder_array = []
for i in range(0,number_in_array):
    item_in_array = int(input("Enter no "+str(i+1)+" item : "))
    array.append(item_in_array)
print("Your array is :")
print(array)
divisor = int(input("Enter the number to divide array with : "))
def decider(function):
    def whenzero(array,divisor):
        for i in range(0,number_in_array):
            if array[i] == 0:
                print("Division is not possible")
                array.pop(i)
            else:
                return function(array,divisor)
        return whenzero()
@decider
def divide(array,divisor):
    for i in range(0,number_in_array):
        remainder = array[i] % divisor
        remainder_array.append(remainder)
    print(remainder_array)
divide(array,divisor)
```

Thank you Anwarvic it did solve the nonetype error but when i want it to display "not possible" when a item in list is 0 it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/acer/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Practice.py", line 26, in <module>
    divide(array, divisor, number_in_array,remainder_array)
  File "C:/Users/acer/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Practice.py", line 14, in whenzero
    if array[i] == 0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I edited the code as follows:

```
# to print array of items of remainders
number_in_array = int(input("How many numbers do you want in the array? "))
array = []
remainder_array = []
for i in range(0,number_in_array):
    item_in_array = int(input("Enter no "+str(i+1)+" item : "))
    array.append(item_in_array)
print("Your array is :")
print(array)
divisor = int(input("Enter the number to divide array with : "))
def decider(function):
    def whenzero(array,divisor,number_in_array,remainder_array):
        for i in range(0,number_in_array):
            if array[i] == 0:
                print("Division is not possible")
                array.pop(i)
            else:
                return function(array,divisor,number_in_array,remainder_array)
    return whenzero
@decider
def divide(array,divisor,number_in_array,remainder_array):
    for i in range(0,number_in_array):
        remainder = array[i] % divisor
        remainder_array.append(remainder)
    print(remainder_array)
divide(array, divisor, number_in_array,remainder_array)
```

Comment: Please add the full trace of your error... also, tell us more about what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I am trying to learn how to use decorators, this program is made to create a list of remainders and return not possible when a item in list is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, all you need to do is to return `whenzero` from `decider` like so:

```
def decider(function):
    def whenzero(array, divisor):
        ...
    return whenzero    #<--- without parentheses and outside whenzero()

...
```

Decorators are a design pattern that can be used to derive new functionality to your code at the last moment. I really suggest reading this [blog post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorator-method-python-design-patterns/)  to know more.